# Value of binded property don´t change when enter text in textbox (INotifyPropertyChanged implemented, MVVM)

Tags: wpf, data-binding, properties, user-controls, inotifypropertychanged

I am trying to realize Wordle(Game) in WPF as a project to practice. In the ViewModel I have a Property(e.g. FirstWord) for the first, second, third, fourth and fifth word, all of which have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented. I would like to avoid creating a property for every single textbox (would be 5x5). Therefore, my model consists of 1st letter, 2nd letter, 3rd letter, etc. In XAML the binding looks like this: {Binding FirstWord.FirstLetter, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}.

When debugging, the program does not even jump into the setter, it was not detected that the value has changed. What can be the reason for this?

ViewModel

```
public class WordleViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private int counter;
        public string solutionWord;

        private static int[] _stateColor = new int[5];
        public static int[] StateColor
        {
            get { return _stateColor;} private set { _stateColor = value; } 
        }

        private SafeWordsModel _firstWord;
        public SafeWordsModel FirstWord
        {
            get { return _firstWord; }
            set
            {
                _firstWord = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        //....

        public WordleViewModel()
        {
            solutionWord = "TESTE";
        }
     }
```

Model (Do I really need variable + Property and the INotifyChanged here?)

```
public class SafeWordsModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private string _firstLetter;
        private string _secondLetter;
        private string _thirdLetter;
        private string _fourthLetter;
        private string _fifthLetter;

        public string FirstLetter
        {
            get { return _firstLetter; }
            set { _firstLetter = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
        public string SecondLetter
        {
            get { return _secondLetter; }
            set { _secondLetter = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
        public string ThirdLetter
        {
            get { return _thirdLetter; }
            set { _thirdLetter = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
        public string FourthLetter
        {
            get { return _fourthLetter; }
            set { _fourthLetter = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
        public string FifthLetter
        {
            get { return _fifthLetter; }
            set { _fifthLetter = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public SafeWordsModel()
        {
            this.FirstLetter = _firstLetter;
            this.SecondLetter = _secondLetter;
            this.ThirdLetter = _thirdLetter;
            this.FourthLetter = _fourthLetter;
            this.FifthLetter = _fifthLetter;
        }
    }
```

View

```
public WordleView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ViewModel = new WordleViewModel();
        }
        public WordleViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get { return DataContext as WordleViewModel; }
            set { DataContext = value; }
        }

        public void FocusNext(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (((TextBox)sender).MaxLength == ((TextBox)sender).Text.Length)
            {
                // move focus
                var ue = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
                e.Handled = true;
                ue.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
            }
        }
```

XAML for one Word

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                        FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=tbx11}">
                <TextBox x:Name="tbx11"
                         Style="{StaticResource Input_tbx}"
                         TextChanged="FocusNext"
                         Background="{Binding ElementName=Line2_ckb, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource brush1}}"
                         Text="{Binding FirstWord.FirstLetter, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="tbx12"
                         Style="{StaticResource Input_tbx}"
                         TextChanged="FocusNext"
                         Background="{Binding ElementName=Line2_ckb, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource brush2}}"
                         Text="{Binding FirstWord.SecondLetter, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="tbx13"
                         Style="{StaticResource Input_tbx}"
                         TextChanged="FocusNext"
                         Text="{Binding FirstWord.ThirdLetter, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="tbx14"
                         Style="{StaticResource Input_tbx}"
                         TextChanged="FocusNext"
                         Background="{Binding ElementName=Line2_ckb, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource brush4}}"
                         Text="{Binding FirstWord.FourthLetter, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="tbx15" 
                         TextChanged="FocusNext"
                         Style="{StaticResource Input_tbx}"
                         Background="{Binding ElementName=Line2_ckb, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource brush5}}"
                         Text="{Binding FirstWord.FifthLetter, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </StackPanel>
```

ObservableObject Class

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

So far it has always worked well with INotifyPropertyChanged. It should set the value that comes from the textbox accordingly in the property and I can also use this value. Feel free to make suggestions on other places in the code, I'm still very new to WPF.

Comment: As a note, the SafeWordsModel constructor is totally pointless. You do not need to "initialize" the properties like this.

Comment: I thought so but I saw this on a similar question so I tried it surprise it made no difference